# library not found for -lPayPalMobile using Braintree

Tags: ios, xcode, paypal, cocoapods, braintree

Im using Braintree which Ive installed with CocoaPods.

When just building and running I get no error, but when I profile (cmd)+i, I get this

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error: 'library not found for -lPayPalMobile'
```

Im not even using the paypal stuff...

How do I silence this error or how do I fix it?

Files: `// I also use MapBox`

[Podfile.lock](http://justpaste.it/igyg)

[Podfile](http://justpaste.it/igyj)

Comment: What line are you using in your Podfile? Can you post your Podfile.lock as well, so we can see the dependencies and versions?

Comment: @mickeyreiss I added the podfiles

Comment: Can you take a look inside of your Pods directory and see if libPayPalMobile.a is present under Pods/Braintree/PayPal/mSDK?

Comment: @mickeyreiss Its under Pods/Braintree/Braintree/PayPal/mSDK

Comment: Im so confues Im looking in the build settings and everything seems to be right :S

Comment: Are you able to post a zip of your entire project? I'm not able to reproduce on my end when I do a cocoapods integration of 3.5.0 from scratch.

Comment: I did something in Edit scheme and the error disappeared :s I dont remember what I did, i tried a loooot of things haha. Thanks for your help anyways, appreciated :)